# Convert meminfo kB to bytes

Tags: memory, proc

To convert the readings in /proc/meminfo from "kB" to bytes, should I multiply by 1024, or 1000?

Comment: 1024 (one thousand twenty four).

Comment: muru - How is this a duplicate?  I already know /proc/meminfo always uses kB

Comment: And this question is for `/proc/meminfo` not `/proc/[pid]/status`...

Answer (score 3):

One convention used to differentiate base 2 and base 10 representations for writing `Kilobyte` is using upper case `K` and lower case `k` respectively. Hence, conversion becomes:

```
1 KB = 1024 bytes  
1 kB = 1000 bytes
```

The kernel, however, uses a buddy system with power-of-two sizes. Hence, appropriate conversion becomes multiplying by 1024.

Here are some links for more information:
[Kernel memory handling](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html)

Comment: That maybe true for other places, but the kernel calls 1024 bytes kB and KB somewhat indiscriminately.

Comment: You are right. And I made an edit above to fix it.